# How to draw coastlines over a custom map without resampling

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I would like to display a satellite image (preferably using python, but other solutions are welcome). It consists in a floating-point parameter P, with dimension NxM, and each pixel is geolocated by the fields latitude and longitude (each of size NxM). So I would like to:

(1) create an image of parameter P with an associated color scale. The image should not be resampled, so it should have dimension NxM

(2) display coastlines over this image

Currently, I can do (1) using PIL. I can also use the basemap library to display an image and the coastlines, but I don't know how to do it without reprojection, by staying in the image native projection with size NxM.

Edit: the parameter P does not contain any information about the coastline. Only the location (lat, lon) of the pixels should be used to overlay the coastline. The coordinates for the coastline can be obtained from [gshhs](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/shorelines/gshhs.html) for example. gshhs is actually used in the basemap library.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is enhance the boundaries between land and water, it might be good to use a high-pass filter.

For instance, start out with Lena:
[image]

and apply a highpass filter:
[image]
<sub>(source: [kiranisingh at sites.google.com](https://sites.google.com/site/kiranisingh/lena.tif))</sub>

then overlay the highpass on top of the original:
[image]

(more details and examples can be found [here](http://www.theparticle.com/cs/bc/mcs/notes0004.html)).

You can find filters in scipy [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html).

Answer (score 0):

For those in the community still looking for an answer to this question, the method which I am currently implementing (for v. similar purposes - I'm trying to test the geolocation of satellite data) requires a landmask.

There are landmask datasets available all over the place online, each with different rules and characteristics. I am working with netCDF4 data in python and my landmask is a gridded .nc dataset in which ocean elements are valued as 1 and land elements are valued as 0.

Iterating through my satellite data I multiply each latitude and longitude value by the number of elements per degree in the landmask. In my case there are 120 elements per degree in lat/lon, so

```
lon_inds = (lons*120).astype(int)
lat_inds = (lats*120).astype(int)
```

A more general way of writing this would involve substituting 120 for

```
len(lons)/360
len(lats)/180
```

respectively. Both examples of these operations can be done nearly instantaneously if using numpy arrays (which is the case for the python netCDF4 module).

Now I create a mask of my own: it must have the same dimensions as the data array (for those not intimately acquainted with satellites, the data, lats and lons arrays will all have identical dimensions):

```
my_mask = np.zeros(data.shape, dtype=int)
```

Now all we need to do is replace values in the mask where there is a coastline. This is done by iterating through the lat_inds and lon_inds arrays, looking up the value in the landmask of

```
landmask[lon_inds[i,j],lat_inds[i,j]]
```

and changing the value of

```
mask[i,j]
```

to 1 if any of the neighbors

```
landmask[lon_inds[i,j]-1,lat_inds[i,j]]
landmask[lon_inds[i,j]+1,lat_inds[i,j]]
landmask[lon_inds[i,j],lat_inds[i,j]-1]
landmask[lon_inds[i,j],lat_inds[i,j]+1]
```

are not equal to 0 (of course, a smoother coastline can be generated by adding in the diagonal neighboring cells, but this should not be necessary as hopefully you should be using a landmask dataset with sharper spatial resolution than your satellite data).

Comment: remember to check the metadata of your landmask to verify that ocean is marked as 1 and land is marked as 0. this could easily be the other way around, or there could be more than two values available, depending on the landmask.